# jqGrid NavBar custom HTML

Tags: jqgrid

I need help with jQuery [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) and subgrid. 
I am able to create a Subgrid inside my jqGrid succesfully. The next step is to add a custom option list in the main grid navbar somewhere so that depending on which option the user selects, a different kind of subgrid opens.
Is it possible to add custom options to the jqGrid navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only standard way to add custom element in the navBar is to use [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) method which add a button.

If you want to add another custom HTML elements you have to do this manually with respect of some jQuery function like [jQuery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/). I recommend you to read the code of [navSeparatorAdd](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js#L1822) and [navButtonAdd](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js#L1773) functions.